# Javascript: How to get numbers out of a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, object, split

```
data = [ RowDataPacket { test: '12312311' },
    RowDataPacket { test: '12312312' },
    RowDataPacket { test: '12312313' } ]
```

I would like to get the numbers from this object into an array in Javascript.
I already tried it with `.split(/(\d+)/);` but I  get this error in Chrome:

> *Uncaught TypeError: data.split is not a function*.

How can I extract the numbers?

Comment: It seems you mix JavaScript Object and JSON here. What you have there is already a JS object and no JSON

Comment: That's not JSON, that's an array of RowDataPackets.

Comment: data.map(each => parseInt(each.test))

Comment: In order for split to work `data` would need to be a string. But really no point in changing an Object to a string to do split on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt will not work because `.split()` is a *string* method - it's used for breaking up a string into an array. You *already have* an array. JSON seems to be irrelevant here, as what you've shared is not JSON.

You can use [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to mutate each member of an array. You want to get each member's `test` value, and parse it.

```js
var data = [ { test: '12312311' }, { test: '12312312' }, { test: '12312313' } ];
var result = data.map(obj => parseInt(obj.test));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method in combination with [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to return a new array. `+` can be used as a coercion operator to change string values into numbers.

```
data.map(({test}) => +test);
```

```js
let data = [ { test: '12312311' }, { test: '12312312' }, { test: '12312313' } ],
    
r = data.map(({test}) => +test);

console.log(r);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is as easy as a simple forEach. But first you should ignore *RowDataPacket* somehow, then below code should work.

```
var numbers = [];
data.forEach(function( item ) {
  numbers.push(parseInt(item.test));
});
```